# Getting numbers from character column in T-SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server

I work with SQL Server. In my database I have a column `UniqueId` which is `nvarchar`, and contains strings with characters and numbers. I want to create another column (`CleanColumn`) getting only numbers from the column `UniqueId`, and if there aren't numbers using the whole string. Also I should lose leading zeros from column `UniqueId`.

Is it possible in T-SQL? Or I have to use C# for that?

The column `UniqueId` contains for example: :

```
A01943486
102-2009-1008
A-146
0622008081A
Ematol OPBG
Yavuz1098083
Yeter1391671
YKM
Zabit1446123
Zekerya13128
Zeynep1045201
```

Comment: Could you explain the purpose of this change? If you want to preserve the a ll-letters records then your new column should still be a nvarchar column with the same problems (?) of the current column

Comment: Thank you for your interest. It is just a client request, it's not so logical. They wanted to order the report by CleanColumn (as numbers), but many strings didn't have numbers in the UniqueId column, so they had to include strings as well.

Comment: And so the whole purpose of sorting can be ditched. Probably a better approach is to fill the column with zero in front of each number and strings and then do the sorting. You can get some ideas from this question: [Formatting Numbers by padding with leading zeros in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520661/formatting-numbers-by-padding-with-leading-zeros-in-sql-server/9520749#9520749)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is q quick UDF which will return numbers only or the original string

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[udfNumbersOnly](@String varchar(250))
Returns Varchar(250)
As
Begin
    Declare @RetVal varchar(250) = @String
    ;with cteChar as (Select Cnt=1,Str=Char(1) Union All Select Cnt=B.Cnt+1,Str=Char(B.Cnt+1) From cteChar as B Where B.Cnt <= 255)
    Select @RetVal = Replace(@RetVal,Str,'') From cteChar where str not like '[0-9]' Option (maxrecursion 256)
    Return case when IsNull(@RetVal,'')='' then @String else cast(cast(@RetVal as decimal(20,0)) as varchar(250)) end
END

Select [dbo].[udfNumbersOnly]('0622008081A')   -- Returns 0622008081
Select [dbo].[udfNumbersOnly]('YKM')           -- Returns YKM
```

So in your case

```
Update YourTableName Set CleanColumn = [dbo].[udfNumbersOnly](UniqueId)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works great. Could you please change the code a little bit to avoid leading zeros? 622008081 instead of 0622008081?

Comment: Updated to remove leading zeros

Comment: Thank you again :) I am sorry  I found a message 'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Ematol OPBG' to data type int' when I have tried `Select [dbo].[udfNumbersOnly]('Ematol OPBG')`. For `Select [dbo].[udfNumbersOnly]('102-2009-1008')` I have a message 'The conversion of the varchar value '10220091008' overflowed an int column.'

Comment: I updated the answer to include one more cast to varchar  this should do the trick

Comment: Hold on 1 second.  I never imagined such a long numeric string.   update in one minute

Comment: OK, rather than convert to int to remove the leading zeros, I convert to decimal(20,0).  You could push that up IF you think the number would be more than 20 digits.

Comment: Update is avail for test

Comment: I shot myself in the foot, when I added the logic to strip leading zeros.  Apologies, lack of imagination on my part

Comment: Glad to know.  Just goes to show you, testing on REAL data is the ultimate test.  Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression `/[0-9]+/` (OR) `\d+`. A sample code given below (using `C#`)

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> str = new List<string>() { "A01943486", "102-2009-1008", "A-146", "0622008081A", 
                                                "Ematol OPBG", "Yavuz1098083", "Yeter1391671"};
        List<int> extractedNumbers = new List<int>();

        Regex reg = new Regex("[0-9]+");

        foreach (var item in str)
        {
            Match m = reg.Match(item);
            if (m.Success)
            {
                int num = Convert.ToInt32(m.Value.TrimStart('0'));
                extractedNumbers.Add(num);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. So, I work in ASP.NET MVC C# project with Entity Framework. Do you know how to update "CleanColumn"and UniqueId (instead of T-SQL)  in Entity Framework in the same time?

Comment: @alenan2013, be it EF/MVC it's C# code and so you can wrap the posted answer code in a method and call that method. About how to update cleancolumn column in your DB table using EF ... that's a separate question and so would suggest you to post another question/thread for that.

Answer (score 0):

With a disclaimer that this design seems strange and problematic, **Yes** - it's possible:

You can [find the first number in the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13382609/in-sql-server-can-you-find-the-first-number-in-a-string) then [check if cast is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14719760/sql-server-check-to-see-if-cast-is-possible) and then use a [case statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) to actually cast it.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I will try.